# Provide Doctrine with custom cache factory for second level cache

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, second-level-cache

Background: we're using Symfony 3.1 + Doctrine 2.5.5 + symfony doctrine bundle.

While trying to enable second level caching for our entities, we have encountered the following issue. If we use NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, everything works fine. However, when we tried to use READ_WRITE, we got the following error
0)

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to Doctrine\ORM\Cache\Persister\Entity\ReadWriteCachedEntityPersister::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Cache\ConcurrentRegion, instance of Doctrine\ORM\Cache\Region\DefaultRegion given, called in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Cache/DefaultCacheFactory.php on line 133
```

As far as I understood, we need to actually implement our own version of ConcurrentRegion and CacheFactory to make it work (FileLockRegion does not suit us due to its usage of file system to handle cache locks). So I wrote those implementations, but the main issue now lies in following: I cannot find where to put my custom factory class' name in the configuration. We have tried the following locations in config:

1)

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager:  master
        second_level_cache:
            default_cache_factory:
                class: AppBundle\Cache\MyCacheFactory
```

This fails due to

```
Unrecognized option "second_level_cache" under "doctrine.orm"
```

even though in our other project using Symfony 2.8 option "second_level_cache" does not throw any errors.

So we went to doctrine bundle code and found the following node description (vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php:492)

```
->arrayNode('second_level_cache')
                    ->children()
                        ->append($this->getOrmCacheDriverNode('region_cache_driver'))
                        ->scalarNode('region_lock_lifetime')->defaultValue(60)->end()
                        ->booleanNode('log_enabled')->defaultValue($this->debug)->end()
                        ->scalarNode('region_lifetime')->defaultValue(0)->end()
                        ->booleanNode('enabled')->defaultValue(true)->end()
                        ->scalarNode('factory')->end()
                    ->end()
```

So we decided we should try this config in our master entity manager section:
2)

```
second_level_cache:
                region_cache_driver:
                    type: memcache
                enabled: true
                log_enabled: true
                factory: AppBundle\Cache\MyCacheFactory
                regions:
                    hour_region:
                        lifetime: 3600
```

However, even though this config is considered valid, when we actually try to access the entity with configured caching, we get the error 0), which makes us think that this option is being ignored by doctrine/symfony.

Is there any way to do it via .yml config at all? [Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html#enable-second-level-cache) only propose to implement CacheFactory and provide a PHP code example, but it's still quite unclear where should this PHP code go, even if we decide to abandon the idea of putting our class in .yml config and go the PHP way.

Answer (score 0):

Use type - filelock for configurate FilelockRegion

```
regions:
  default:
    cache_driver:
      type: service
      id: 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache'
    lifetime: 3600
    type: filelock
```